# TCP/IP with SSL - Delphi and Indy10

Tags: delphi, ssl, c++builder, indy10

I want to do a TCP/IP SSL connection with Indy10 sockets and an SSLIOHandler.

Do I need a Certificate and Private key on my side?

Comment: From the Related list that appeared as you were typing your question, and listed at the right of your question now: [Delphi - SSL TCP communication with Indy components](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11844630/62576). Sample code can be found via Google or Bing. Vague information like "when I try to send data the remote host disconnects me" isn't useful, and as you've posted no code that shows what you're doing now it's pretty difficult to say what you might need to do differently.

Comment: Ken, I already read all relevant posts.  I had a specific question and Remy answered it, just like I hoped he would when I posted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a ceritificate only if the remote party requires it, otherwise it is optional.